# System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Unspecified error - Only on some machines

Tags: c#, asp.net, oledb

I have a .NET framework 3.5 application that connects via OleDb to a SQL Server 2000 database. Everything was working fine, but now only some users are getting this error:

> Message: Unspecified error
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Unspecified error
>   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader.ProcessResults(OleDbHResult hr)
>   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader.GetRowHandles()
>   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader.ReadRowset()
>   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader.Read()
>   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader.HasRowsRead()
>   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader.NextResult()
>   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method)
>   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader()
>   at Comafi.PymeBC.Webdav.Hibernate.Module.DataBaseConnection.GetData(String
>   texto, CommandType tipo) in C:\Devel\ComafiEmpresas\src\ComafiEmpresas\Comafi.PymeBC.Webdav3\Comafi.PymeBC.Webdav.Hibernate.Module\DataBaseConnection.cs:line 48
>   at Comafi.PymeBC.Webdav.Hibernate.Module.DbFile.GetUniqueFile(String
>   urlPath) in

Here's my connection string

```
<add name="Webdav" 
     connectionString="Provider = SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=DataBaseSource;Initial Catalog=DataBaseName;User Id=User;Password=SomePassword;" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Here's my code. **The line that throws the error is "comando.ExecuteReader()"**

```
public static OleDbConnection GetConnection()
{
    try
    {
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettingsCollection Constrings = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings;
            System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings Constring = Constrings["Webdav"];

            conn.ConnectionString = Constring.ConnectionString;
            conn.Open();
        }

        return conn;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}

public static OleDbDataReader GetData(string texto, CommandType tipo)
{
    var comando = new OleDbCommand
                      {
                          Connection = GetConnection(),
                          CommandText = texto,
                          CommandType = tipo,
                      };

    return comando.ExecuteReader();
}

public static DbFile GetUniqueFile(string urlPath)
        {
            ...

            var data = GetData(....);

            if (data.HasRows)
            {
                data.Read();
                    var file = DbFile.GetObject(data);
                data.Close();
                return file;
            }

            return null;
        }
```

I read a lot of posts about this but none pointed me to the right direction.

Comment: Which line of code throws the exception?  You really should close your connection rather than leave it open like that.

Comment: @dubstylee It's a figure of speech.. come on!!

Comment: @LarsTech I will edit my post, I close the returned Data Reader after I read it, and that is supposed to close the connection

Comment: @Nicole I know, I was being sarcastic :) sorry if that was not obvious.

Comment: You only close it if you have rows.  And even then, you are only closing the Reader, not the connection.  That said, what is the texto string that causes the exception?  Does it happen on any sql call?  The first sql call?  You really haven't given us enough information to help you.

Comment: @dubstylee Sorry, I missunderstud your sarcasm :) I think people are too sensitive on the internet right now, I'm sorry.

Comment: @LarsTech I thought that closing the reader was enough, I'll try closing the connection as well. It happens on every request done by only one user, with different querys.

Comment: Then this is an environment problem on that user's machine.  Showing us this code won't help us since it's, more or less, working code.  You will have to track down what is different for that user.  Permissions?  64-bit?  etc, etc.